# Is Facebook SDK supported on HMS platform

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We are using Facebook ads and facebook analytics and facebook push notification as a marketing events? They have huge conversation ration from these on there app . Is Huawei supporting these on HMS platform .

Is integration available for the Mix Panel Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

1. For facebook analytics and facebook push notification , as these are latest services provided by facebook , please contact facebook support team regarding these services.

Facebook ads:Currently, HUAWEI Ads does not restrict the access to third-party platform SDK for apps. However,  apps also need to comply with the App Gallery release protocol. Please give us some time we need to confirm this with audit team also.

2. Mix Panel Analytics is supported on HMS platform. You can check below reference link , as per Mix Panel support team, it is not dependent on specific app store.

https://community.mixpanel.com/strategy-and-planning-9/does-mixpel-depends-on-google-play-services-4814

Comment: Apps can integrate Facebook ads,but if an ad is frequently displayed, no matter what the ad is (Huawei, Facebook etc ads), it is not allowed.